# Passing an empty list to a defined-type: possible?

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket

A rookie Racket question. I'm using Krishnamurthi's PLAI textbook for this one, and the associated Racket programming language.

Now, let's say that I have a defined type as such:

```
(define-type Thingy
 [thingy (num number?)])
```

So, is there any circumstance at all under which I could get this `thingy` to accept an empty list `'()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty list is not a number, so the type definition you have will not accept it.

You can use `(lambda (x) (or (number? x) (null? x)))` instead of `number?` to accept either a number or an empty list, but I have no idea why you would want to do that.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot :)
Your finishing comment: is the act of returning empty lists frowned upon by Schemers? I was just doing this to cover a trivial case, btw.

Comment: Well, if your function normally returns lists of a bunch of items, and you're returning an empty bunch of items, then an empty list is appropriate. What "trivial case" are you talking about?

Comment: Scheme doesn't really have a concept of "null" (in the way that Java and similar languages have), so if your program relies on such a concept, then you should rethink your design.

Comment: Can I refine this? Scheme has null--it's the empty list, as you conjecture--but packages such as Krishnamurthi's define-type reject the automatic lazy-man insertion of this into every data definition. If you want a thingy with no number, you need a data definition (as Chris mentions) that explicitly allows this. Note that this is a property of Krishnamurthi's define-type, and not of Scheme in general (though it's certainly a good idea, in my opinion). More constructively: in what case do you want this?

Comment: @John: Of course `null?` tests for the empty list, so it that sense it's null, but (if I understand correctly) it's not intended for use in the same way null is used in Java, as a "this has no value" marker (and like you say, it's its own distinct type, and cannot be lumped in with other types like you can with Java). That's what I meant when I added the "in a way that Java and similar languages have" comment.

Answer (score 2):

As described in http://docs.racket-lang.org/plai/plai-scheme.html, define-type can take several different variants.  It can define a disjoint datatype in a way that allows the language itself to help you write safer code.

For example:

```
#lang plai

(define-type Thingy
 [some (num number?)]
 [none])
```

Code that works with Thingys now need to systematically process the two possible kinds of Thingys.  When you use type-case, it will enforce this at compile time: if it sees that you have written code that doesn't account for the possible kinds of Thingy, it'll throw a compile-time error.

```
;; bad-thingy->string: Thingy -> string
(define (bad-thingy->string t)
  (type-case Thingy t
    [some (n) (number->string n)]))
```

This gives the following compile-time error:

```
type-case: syntax error; probable cause: you did not include a case for the none variant, or no else-branch was present in: (type-case Thingy t (some (n) (number-> string n)))
```

And that's right: the code has not accounted for the case of none.